# My Website does not display properly on resolutions above 1024

Tags: layout, web, resize, liquid

I recently developed a website that looks good on 1024 resolution but gets messed up on larger resolutions. Here are the links to the files you will probably need to review: [CSS for the site](http://inecnursing.org/inec.css), [CSS for the menu bar](http://inecnursing.org/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css). It's a PHP file but I've already linked to the included HTML files.

I have a regular 17' screen while the client has a widescreen. She sees white space on the right side that I don't. I've only seen it as I have used the website viewlike.us to test on different resolutions. How can I make it so it resizes proportionality? Thanks.

Comment: no link to the HTML or the page

Comment: I'm sorry. It was originally included, I think but I exceeded my max amount of links. The site is inecnursing.org. I've made some changes since the original post. I think I'll have to make a bigger background image to stretch across for higher resolutions.Things are lining up but they aren't properly spreading across the page ng it look liek only part of the page is being used.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set the body to be 1024 px

```
body {
width:1024px;
background-image:url(images/top_background.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#FFF;
}
```

You don't want to do that, what you usually do is to have a page wrapper where you set the size to be 1024px.

For instance you can have this in html

```
<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body>
      <div id="pageWrapper">
        <!-- all your content here -->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then in the css you can have something like this:

```
#pageWrapper {
    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm going to try it in a second. I just wanted to first add that I set the body to 100% initially but that casued distortion in resolution beyond 1024px so I set it to 1024 which is the length of the background image. As an additional quick question since I am fairly new to making responsive design thus the problems I am running into. When you have a background image such as mine which makes up the header fo the site what should its dimensions be so it works on any resolution? Should I make a gigantic picture so it can "shrink" accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You usually have an structure like this:

```
<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body>
      <div id="header-wrapper>
         <div id="header>
            <!-- header content here -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="pageWrapper">
        <!-- all your content here -->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then you can set an image for the header and another for the body, or an image for the header and a background color for the body. It all depends on what are you doing.

The background images usually are not that big. What you usually have are images or patterns that can be repeated either on X or Y or both. On the css you can have something like:

```
#headerWrapper {
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url("/img/background.png") repeat-x;
}
```

With this the image will repeat horizontally on the header. Then you can set another background for the body, or just a background color.

Again, it depends a lot on what are you trying to achive.

Good luck!!

Comment: Thank you for that! I think that's the final solution I need.